# Deeple translate Apple Script?

Tags: applescript, translate

I have Apple Script for Google Translator like:

function run(input, parameters) {

```
var output = "http://translate.google.com/#auto/ru/" + encodeURIComponent(input)

return output;
```

}

But for deeple.com this is not workint, because I got empty window:

function run(input, parameters) {

```
var output = "https://www.deepl.com/translator/ru/" + decodeURIComponent(input)

return output;
```

}

How I can fix it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please include a minimal example of your workflow - actions providing the input (those looks like Automator `Run JavaScript` actions), the `encodeURIComponent` and `decodeURIComponent` handlers, etc - so others can run it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes here is correct variant:

```
function run(input, parameters) {
    
    var output = "https://www.deepl.com/translator//" + encodeURIComponent(input) + "/ru/"

    return output;
}
```